# Highcharts filter is not working in Codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

I created a Highchart in Codeigniter to populate item issued status in stock. The chart is generated correctly as follows :
[image]

I used the following code to do this.

Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Chart extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('data');
}

public function index()
{
$this->load->view('chart');
}

public function data()
{

$data = $this->data->get_data();

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Branch';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Issued Quantity';

foreach ($data as $row)
{
$category['data'][] = $row->branch;
$series1['data'][] = $row->issued_qty;
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
}
```

Model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Data extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
// Call the Model constructor
parent::__construct();
}

function get_data($id)
{    
     $this->db->select('sur.update_stock_id, sus.branch_id, sus.request_no, sus.billed_date, 
     store_branch.branch_name AS branch,
     si.item_id, si.item_name AS item,  tf.avqty,   sur.r_qty as r_qty, sur.ap_qty as ap_qty, 
     tf1.issued_qty');
     $this->db->from('store_update_request sur');
     $this->db->join('store_update_stock sus', 'sus.update_stock_id=sur.update_stock_id', 'left');      
     $this->db->join('store_branch', 'sus.branch_id=store_branch.branch_id', 'left');
     $this->db->join('store_item si', 'sur.item=si.item_id', 'left');       
     
     $this->db->join('(select update_stock_id, item, is_qty AS issued_qty 
         from store_update_issue            
         where store_update_issue.status=1 
         ) AS tf1', 
         'si.item_id=tf1.item AND sur.update_stock_id = tf1.update_stock_id','left' );
                 
     $this->db->join('(select item, sum(qty)  AS avqty 
         from store_update_stock_details            
         where store_update_stock_details.status=1 
         group by item) AS tf', 'si.item_id=tf.item', 'left');
     $this->db->where(array('sus.status' => 1 ));     
     
     $query = $this->db->get();
     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return $query->result();
     }
     return false;
}

function getBranch()
    {
        $this->db->select('branch_id, branch_name');
        $this->db->from('store_branch');        
        $this->db->order_by('branch_id', 'ASC');
        return $this->db->get();
    } 
}
```

View :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stationary / Consumables Issuing Status',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Qty'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>' +
                        this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("data", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });

</script>
<a href="<?= site_url('welcome') ?>"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Back to Home"></a>

<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/highcharts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/exporting.js'></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Problem :
But this code is generating all the issued quantities for all branches.

Desired Output :
I am trying to get branch wise issued data by applying a branch filter for the chart.

Then I change the view & model as follows to do this :
Controller :

```
public function index()
{
$data['branch_list'] = $this->data->getBranch();
$this->load->view('chart');
}
```

model :

```
function get_data($branch)
........
........
$this->db->where(array('sus.status' => 1, 'store_branch.branch_id' => $branch)); 

function getBranch()
    {
        $this->db->select('branch_id, branch_name');
        $this->db->from('store_branch');        
        $this->db->order_by('branch_id', 'ASC');
        return $this->db->get();
    } 
}
```

View :
(Added New Code)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select name="branch" id="branch" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Branch</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($branch_list->result_array() as $row) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row["branch_id"] . '">' . $row["branch_name"] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
function load_branchwise_data(branch title)
{
    var temp_title = title + '' + branch;
    $.ajax({
        url:od:"POST",
        data"<?php echo base_url(); ?>charts/branch_data",
        meth:{branch:branch},
        
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data)
        {
            drawBranchWiseChart(data, temp_title);
        }
    })
}
?>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#branch').change(function(){
        var branch = $(this).val();
        if(branch != '')
        {
            load_branchwise_data(branch, 'Item Issuing Summary - ');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Current Issue :
After doing this changes to the code the chart outs the blank view. What did I miss here ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi @mcode, do you get any errors? The problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about other functionalities. To apply some filters on a chart, you may need to use chart.update api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update, setData api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData or some other methods from Highcharts API.

Comment: @magdalena. Didn't get any error. Outs a blank view only.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, as this issue does not appear to be related to Highcharts itself, I am unable to provide further assistance. Perhaps someone familiar with CodeIgniter might be able to help you find the right solution, Regards!